# Money vs Monies

Tags: meaning

How would the meaning in the following phrase change if "monies" is replaced with "money"?

> universities would be diverted from basic research by the lure of new
>   development **monies** from “the marketplace,”

Comment: _Monies_ is the word one uses when money doesn't matter.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Garner in *Modern American Usage* has a good entry on this. He says:

> While *money* generally functions in collective senses (we made a lot of money on that deal), *moneys* is frequently used, especially in financial and legal contexts, to denote "discrete sums of money" or "funds" (many federal and state moneys were budgeted for disaster relief).

So if you want to emphasise that the funds are coming from various sources, use the plural *moneys* or *monies*, otherwise use *money* as the more common and unmarked variant.

Answer (score 13):

The collective noun dilemma again.

- Soil or soils
- Money or monies
- Equipment or equipments
- Furniture or furnitures
- Fish or fishes
- Data or datas
- Schema or Schemas

?

Illustration

Soils = types of soil

> He is a soil expert. He is looking at all the soil in my farm. He has seen the soils of all the farms in this area. In fact, he has seen most of the soils in almost every region in the world.

Monies = instances of money

> We have paid good money to bribe the corrupt officials of this town. We have paid good money in many villages and towns. Of all the corrupt monies we have paid, this one is the best.

Equipments = instances of equipment

> We will be moving all their office equipment to their new office. We also have to move their manufacturing equipment. They may plan to move their network equipment too. Of all the equipments, their manufacturing equipment is the most difficult to move.

IMO, the plurality of instances of equipment should still be "equipment" not "equipments".

*Datas & Schemas? Why can't the engineers in Google and Microsoft get it? That*

- *singular = datum, plural = data (no such thing as datas until they invented the word)*
- *singular = schema, plural = schemata (Got it???!!!!!)*

Comment: +1: good examples! Trying to fit the datum / data war is a lost cause though I think -- along with agenda / agendum...

Comment: @Blessed Geek - Why do you believe that equipment-equipments should be treated differently? Is there a reason that you have in mind?

Comment: `schemata`?  wth?  I've heard of datum/data, but schema/*schemata*? Well I'll take your word for it...  "I am currently designing database schemata."

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/schemata

Answer (score 2):

*Money* is the more logical and the preferred form, but *monies* is a frequent variant.

In the "Oxford Dictionary of English", Second Edition, Revised - eBook Copyright 2010, we read:

> (**moneys** or **monies**) FORMAL sums of money.

Also, in "The New Oxford American Dictionary", Second Edition - eBook Copyright 2008, we read:

> **monies**: plural form of MONEY, as used in financial context.

Considering that your sentence is not expressed in financial context, I would say that *money* fits better your case.

Comment: @simchona - Really, my eBook is called "Oxford Dictionary of English", Second Edition, Revised - eBook Copyright 2010, as I directly read.

Comment: ok, my mistake. Feel free to edit it back--sorry for the error

Comment: @Carlo_R.- I would say the example _is_ in a financial context and `monies` is exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

Use **monies** when referring to money collected from different countries' denominations.  Otherwise, money is considered plural (just look in your wallet)!  That's not a collection of **monies**, but an assortment of money (US dollars/cents). Universities may collect tuition for national and international students.  Thus, they've collected **monies**; national and international funds.