# When do you use 'monies' in plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Money vs Monies](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65366/money-vs-monies)

I have seen the plural of money, monies, used.  It sounds a bit awkward but extravagant and I like the sound but not sure when it is correct to use it instead of the regular singular.  Any idea?

Comment: if closed as a dupe, shouldn't the closer submit the original thread URL?

Comment: The closer *has no other choice*. The URL is *added automatically*.

Comment: Look about four inches (10 cm) above your comment.

Answer (score 4):

In ordinary usage "money" is a mass noun with a collective sense, and there is no need to pluralize it.

But in law and accounting, money is a countable noun which can be pluralized to express the idea of individual sum of money; in this case you can use both "moneys" and "monies". (Reference: CGEU)