# Why can't we say "informations"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

Why can't we use the word *information* in the plural form?
"Give me all the informations you've got", even if it's wrong, sounds more beautiful to my non-native ear than "give me all the information you've got", and I don't know why.

**Edit:** This is not a duplicate question since I know that *information* is a mass noun; what I am asking is, why can't it be in plural like some other mass nouns can? Why is it like that when it seems more correct with *s* at the end?

Comment: You mean "all the information you've got"... What **sounds** good doesn't necessarily mean that it's right :(

Comment: @itsols, thanks for the remark, i have edited the sentence.

Comment: [Information](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/information) is a [classic mass noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81001/uncountable-nouns). *Informations* do exist, but only in a very specific context.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65366/money-vs-monies/65427#65427

Comment: @AndrewLeach, can you give me an example where to use the word `informations` ?

Comment: In the [ODO entry](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/information) I linked to earlier.

Comment: I can’t lay my hands on the reference, but David Crystal has reported an increase in the use of _informations_ by native speakers, as a result of its use by non-native speakers. The OED has 59 citations showing its use.

Comment: I see, I also used to say it a lot, as a non-native speaker.

Comment: I actually tend to agree that the question is not quite a duplicate, but that's in no small part due to the fact that I don't understand what the question here *is*. In fact, as demonstrated by the accepted answer, even the OP agrees it's rhetorical at best.

Comment: It's actually the comments on the best answer that i liked most, it made me understand that sometimes you just can't agree with the grammar, but that's what it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because we don't. I'm sorry, but that is the whole of the answer. Languages are as they are, not as anybody (native or foreign) wants them to be.

Comment: But Colin, we can't build a correct understanding of the language if we keep saying languages are as they are.

Comment: Why not? That's how children learn it. But seriously, I realise that this is a problem for learners of a language, but I don't think there is an answer. Whatever dictionary you use, it is wrong. Even if it is an online dictionary updated daily, there will be words and meanings that it hasn't got yet. And grammar books are worse, because they are nearly always incomplete, out of date, and sometimes plain wrong even at the time they're published, and get progressively more so as the language changes under them.

Comment: Dictionary compilers have to decide on whether to 'endorse' (ie include) a string they've come across - from what I've seen of the process, a single example wouldn't convince most boards. That doesn't mean the string wouldn't be accepted a year later. Some 'words' are also removed as they fall out of use. Calling this process 'wrong' may not be the best description. But I agree that I've yet to meet a grammar I agree with totally.

Comment: @Tech Support I've upvoted Colin's depressing answer because I feel it's nearer the truth than the usual 'because it's a non-count noun' or (better) 'because it's usually a non-count noun'. When you think about it, giving it such a label doesn't explain **why** it isn't used in plural form (ie **why** it's non-count). In fact, modern usage is licensing countification, as Andrew Leach mentions above. It would be better to look at inherent nondiscreteness v divisiblity - but this doesn't give predictable results. "Furniture," which takes only singular verb forms, is etically discrete.

Comment: For another illustration of the principle that the count/non-count distinction lies not in an object but rather in the expression that refers to it, consider the English words "fruit" and "vegetables". The objects that these words describe are, objectively speaking, similar (that is, they're all edible plant parts); yet the word "fruit" is (usually) non-count, whereas "vegetables" is a plural count form. One can see that the difference is in the language, not in the reality of the objects.

Comment: Meanwhile, German has a general word for "vegetables" that, like English "fruit", is (usually) non-count: das Gemüse. British English has a slang word for "vegetables" that acts the same way: "veg" [rhymes with "edge"]. (Wikipedia: Mass Nouns)

Comment: This is the kind of answers i was looking for, and it's not a duplicate question since i was searching for the reason why, the other questions didn't provide that. I guess Mr Collin, and Mr Edwin, you made the thing totally clear.

Comment: This is the poorest answer to any question on this site. And it's certainly not the whole answer.

Answer (score 24):

Because information is a [mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun), i.e. uncountable.  In the same way you would say *give me all the water in your bucket*, rather than *give me all the waters...*

For discrete items of information, you could use *facts*.

Comment: Yes, you're correct about 'water in your bucket(s)' but we *do* use the plural like in 'trouble waters', don't we?

Comment: It's trouble**d** waters, but yes we do.  And many other phrases "still waters runs deep" for example. A decent dictionary definition will make clear those meanings.  You could always substitute *sand* for *water* if you want a better example.

Comment: @ Chris: Then someone would point to expressions like [*desert sands*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22desert+sands%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and [*the sands of time*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+sands+of+time%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can't deny that - maybe "What's a perfect mass noun example" should be a question!  Especially as (almost)anything food/drink related could be taken as *portion of...*.

Comment: @ChrisH I don't think there are any instances where a mass noun cannot be countified. *Air* (as in what we breathe) is probably the nearest, but even then different planets would have different airs. [*Airs and graces* is not the same!]

Comment: My best example was *knowledge*, for which I can't think of a plural sense.  But I agree in principle.

Comment: @Chris: Nice try, but [no cigar](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knowledges&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I knew I'd failed - but didn't expect a simple google search to give such a solid example of the fact (I didn't test it myself as the internet has almost as many misspellings as cats).  On a more serious note, I guess for any *stuff* there can be a set of varieties of *stuff*, i.e. a set of *stuffs* - it's just that some are more obscure than others.

Comment: I've come across _furnitures_ (Louis XIV, Louis XV ...) but not _cutleries_.

Comment: One could also use  _piece(s) of_ information to make it discrete and countable.